# Dealing with Word spell check in technical documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, dictionary

I have waste millions of hours clicking the *Ignore Once* button in Word, while trying to spell check a document related to development. Be that something light on terms like a proposal or something worse like technical specs.

I'm beginning to think that this is a huge waste and someone may have developed a dictionary for Word with common development terms that I could add and no longer have this problem.

Does such a dictionary exist or is there some other tricks to use to improve this process?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Judging from your image I'd say the best way to deal with that would be to use styles properly. You can set individual styles to be ignored when spell-checking which is *very* handy for things like source code or random nonsense. This can be found on the "Format" button when editing styles.

I'd think that for actual *words* that appear in your text you would probably want to add them to the dictionary instead of ignoring them over and over again each session.

But I'm assuming here, that your uses of unknown words are pretty confined, in this case to code blocks, examples, listings, etc. This may or may not apply to your case. You certainly won't find a dictionary containing all possible directory names (referring to your screenshot again, here).

Comment: I'll vote this up if you explain how to set up the styles.

Comment: C. Ross: No access to a non-German version of Word here. And I consider styles to be *fundamental* knowledge to use that program. Users who see Word as a fancy typewriter imho wouldn't care about spell checking either.

Comment: +1 for the styles - but it does not provide a technical dictionary which is what I am looking for.

Comment: So what you're really looking for are dictionaries specific to document types?

Answer (score 4):

Try some of the 'Options' mentioned in the lower left hand corner - there's a lot of choices of things to Ignore.

You can also consider 'Add to Dictionary' instead of 'Ignore' - it'll add the words to the dictionary, which will let you (eventually) create your own dictionary of common technical words.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a character style that is not spell-checked (Format, Language, Do not check spelling or grammar in the Modify Style Window) and apply it to all technical terms.  You could also make that style use a fixed-width font.

This may or may not be the solution you're looking for, but it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

For Word 2010:
From Review Menu Ribbon,
Click Spelling and Grammar,
Click Options

Or From File Menu Ribbon,
Click Options,
Click Proofing

At bottom of options page
 click "Hide spelling errors in this document only"

Do same for grammar errors.