# Include Custom Dictionary or Terms in Word Documents

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, dictionary

This is similar to [Dealing with Word spell check in technical documents?](https://superuser.com/questions/56461/dealing-with-word-spell-check-in-technical-documents), but not identical. If a document contains many occurrences of a technical term which is in your own custom dictionary, how can you make Word recognize the term when *others* view the document?

My understanding is that "Ignore All" will travel with the document, as does turning off spell checking for a section via the Review->Language options. If I'm not mistaken however, "Add to Dictionary" affects your personal dictionary rather than the document itself. If that's correct, then the technical terms I've defined won't show as errors for me, but it will be full of red squiggly lines again when I share the document with others.

Is there a way to get those custom words to travel with the document?

Comment: Mostly 2013, though I have 2010 on another PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word 2007/2010 Do this:

Start by pressing CTRL-A to select your whole document.

1. Click on the Review tab at the top of the window and then on the Set Language button.
2. Click on the name of the language in the status bar.
3. Add a check mark in the Do not check spelling or grammar option and click OK.

That’s it. The red and green squiggly underlines should have vanished.

Optional. While you are there, to ensure that the recipient sees things exactly as you do, make sure that you set the document display to Final. Change Final Showing Markup -> Final.

[image]

2003:

Goto Menubar > Tools > Language > Set Language > Select Language > Do not check spelling or grammar.

[image]

Comment: This does de-squiggle the view, so it works as a "nuclear option." However, if there's a way to leave spell-check on for the document as a whole & just add recognition of the technical terms—in a portable/transferable way—that would be preferable.